# Python Check if Condition in Loop Changes

Tags: python, linux, networking

I have created a small python script to monitor if an OS (Linux) is able to ping a certain ip address of 10.0.0.1 (router on LAN). This first script works fine but I have to execute the script to have it evaluate the condition each time.

I think I understand that this script simply exits after the condition is evaluated. I tried including a while else loop in the second example below that evaluates the return of the OS call and place this function call in the loop to keep checking if the router was plugged back into the LAN.

Is the correct approach to define a function to evaluate the ping status? I tried adding a function in the last example but it doesn't seem to update.

My goal is to run this script once and have it detect is 10.0.0.1 is up or down when I unplug it from the network or plug it back in.

```
    import os
    import time

    ip = "10.0.0.1"
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " +ip)

    if response != 0:
            print ip, 'is down'
            time.sleep(3)

    else:
       print ip, 'is up!'
```

---

I tried adding the while else loop but the condition doesn't seem to get updated.

```
    import os
    import time

    ip = "10.0.0.1"
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " +ip)

    while response != 0:
            print ip, 'is down'
            time.sleep(3)

    else:
    print ip, 'is up!'
```

---

I even tried defining a fuction to evaluate the condition for every iteration of the loop..

```
    import os
    import time


    ip = "10.0.0.1"
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " +ip)

    def checkstatus():
            response = os.system("ping -c 1 " +ip)

    while response != 0:
            print ip, 'is down'
            time.sleep(3)
            checkstatus()# trying to evaluate if status has changed

    while response != 1:
            print ip, 'is up'
            time.sleep(3)
            checkstatus()# trying to evaluate if status has changed
```

**EDIT**

This is how I changed the script and now it works..Just need to slow down the network unreachable stdout.

```
    import os
    import time

    ip = "10.0.0.1"
    while True:
            response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + ip)
            if response == 0:
                    print'connected'
                    time.sleep(.5)
```

New  output **NOTICE print statement connected appears** as **connected**

```
    --- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
    1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.383/0.383/0.383/0.000 ms
    **connected**
    PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.308 ms

    --- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
    1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.308/0.308/0.308/0.000 ms
    ***connected***
```

**New Output after unplugged for a few seconds** (floods screen)

```
    connect: Network is unreachable
    connect: Network is unreachable
    connect: Network is unreachable
    connect: Network is unreachable
    connect: Network is unreachable
```

Nothing too bad but worried this will use many CPU cycles as this script will
be running on a raspberry pi.

Comment: make sure your `time.sleep(.5)` is outside of the `if` statement, otherwise it's not executed in the failure case (pings are spinning back2back)...

Answer (score 2):

The mistake you make is that you look for changes in `response`, which doesn't reflect the network status changes unless you repeat the assignment to it via `response = os.system("ping -c 1 " +ip)`.

Apart from including the assignment inside your loop (as suggested by DeepSpace) you can also change the loop check itself to correctly reflect network status changes (according to your method):

```
while os.system("ping -c 1 " +ip):
    print ip, 'is down'
    time.sleep(3)
```

Similarly, when using `checkstatus()` you'd need to either include `response = checkstatus()` in the loop or use it in the check: `while checkstatus():`.

The last version of your code has a couple of extra problems:

- typically the return code of a program is 0 on success, but it may have multiple non-zero return codes, so your `!= 1` check *might* not work as you'd expect, better use `== 0` check instead.
- the sequenced potentially endless `while` statements won't actually complete unless a certain sequence of the connection state happens. Since your goal is to simply run once and find out the current state of the connection the code would better not depend on such sequence.

Maybe something like this instead?

```
if os.system("ping -c 1 " +ip):
    print ip, 'is down'
else:
    print ip, 'is up'
```

Or, if you prefer one-liners:

```
print ip, 'is ' + 'down' if os.system("ping -c 1 " +ip) else 'up'
```

Comment: Yep, that worked!
See the edit above for the new output. Also, thanks. I assumed returning true was 1 and false was zero.

Answer (score 0):

For your second attempt (with the function), I believe what is happening is that `response` is being defined as a local variable of the function `checkstatus`, which is separate from the global varriable `response`. To reassign the global from the function (and not make a local variable), add the line `global response` to the top of the function body.

Comment: I tried adding the global response statement but it looks like the while loops are not checking or responding to the change in ping status.

Answer (score 0):

The naive way would be to use `while True`:

```
ip = "10.0.0.1"
while True:
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + ip)
    if response == 0:
        break  # or do anything else
        time.sleep(3)
```

A better way is to have the script make a single call to `os.system` then use crontab or Windows Scheduler to run it every X amount of time.

Comment: I am hoping to keep this in a simple python script. The purpose is to always be listening for this IP to respond then perform a curl call to log into the router,authenticate and POST some information. The goal is to automate the router config. I will be adding other functionality to this script when the condition is evaluated to true so.